# Why do editors who remove their edits get featured?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, edits

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710422/pqgetresult-always-returns-null) on Stack Overflow. Someone [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27710422/2) but then reverted the edit (as indicated by "[Edit removed during grace period]").

If the user didn't contribute to improving my question, why does that user appear on the question page as the editor?

---

My arguments against the current behavior:

1. Correctness: Nothing has been edited.
2. Self-promotion: One gets listed as the most recent editor not having edited.
3. Visual clutter: The widget is a distracting cue to browse the revision history, especially if a lower-rep user has modified a higher-rep user's question. (In cases like these, there's no need to view the revision history because no modifications have been made.)

Comment: Yeah, this will remain always (not caching). But I really didn't wondered why is it done in this way before, thats actually interesting.

Comment: You have this tagged as a bug, which it is not. If you just want a general answer, the simplest is "because a revision still exists and that's the way the system works." I get the feeling, though, that you'd like this to change, in which case it'd be better transformed as a feature-request.

Comment: @animuson I didn't know it wasn't a bug. Moved to feature-request. Thanks.

Comment: To go into more detail why the system works that way (currently): because when a user edits a post, their user ID gets permanently cached into a variable on that post as the LastEditorUserId. That only gets updated when another user subsequently edits the post. Reverting that when a user retracts an edit requires crawling through the revision history to find the last revision that qualifies as a "last editor" (since there could be multiple retracted edits). I'm not sure how much Stack Exchange cares about this to change the way the feature behaves.

Comment: I think it is for the sake of simplicity of the implementation. Originally, edits removed during grace period will not generate any revision. Later a feature request to leave a revision is made and fulfilled, so it just display the user who made the last revision regardless.

Comment: @Nit This appears to need to be done during the 5 (or 10? I forget now) minute period immediately following the original post, or maybe the edit must be small enough that the two revisions are merged. (I'm not sure exactly.)

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for explaining, I tried it out because I've never even seen this happen.

Comment: Why not just strike through the "edited x time ago"? That should make it clear that the revision was rolled back.

Comment: This is really a [feature to identify when people are retracting their edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133301/209031). I wouldn't be largely concerned with visual real estate or self promotion.  There are plenty of other ways to enforce self promotion issues if a user is repeatedly misusing this quirk just to appear on someone's revision history, which I greatly doubt.

Comment: I don't think there's really anything all that glamorous about being the most recent editor on some question. The `edited ...` widget is for informational purposes, and if it's not strictly correct all the time, I don't think it's really a big deal.

Answer (score 5):

Rolling back a revision *in general* also counts as an edit. The grace period is fairly irrelevant here.

The "edited by" feature on the questions list is relatively recent. Back in the day, we used a more general "modified by" approach that didn't go into specifics of the last activity. We still retain that when an action doesn't clearly map to making an edit or posting an answer.

All in all, I'm with [JLRishe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1945651/jlrishe) here:

> I don't think there's really anything all that glamorous about being the most recent editor on some question.

We are careful not to attribute authorship to someone who didn't actually post the question. So long as your content isn't negatively affected (and note that we still attribute the post to you as the author), and strictly speaking someone *did* edit it... I'm inclined to call this as working as intended.